# Room and ViewModel, multiple queries?

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

So I have an android application that has a Room database, this backend is managed by a class that acts as a repository which feeds my view model, and then my activity (fragment) observes the view model, (everyone still with me?) in one of my fragments I want to get a list of all the cards (entities) in my database with a clicked value above X but I also want to get all cards that are marked as a favourite regardless of their clicked value.

My current solution is running 2 separate queries from my view model, through my repository and I have my activity observing both queries and combining the lists returned to it, this isn't working properly as my lists are being doubled and I don't have a great place for clearing the lists as the observers come back at different times because they are asynchronous (I'll post all the code).

I think what I want is to combine the queries somehow so that I'm only managing one list but my SQL knowledge isn't great and I'm not sure if this is possible, alternatively I could somehow merge these lists in my repository class but because I'm working with Live Data I'm unsure how to get the data safely to combine the lists, but maybe there is a better solution I'm unaware of but I'll post what I'm doing so far below

**DAO Query**
these are the two queries I run, one gets all cards clicked x amount of times and the other gets all cards marked as favourite, both take a search string which isn't relevant right now

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM card WHERE cardFavourite AND cardWord LIKE :searchWord ORDER BY cardWord ASC")
LiveData<List<Card>> searchFavourites(String searchWord);

@Query("SELECT * FROM card WHERE cardClicked >= :clicks AND cardKeyStage <= :keystage  AND cardWord LIKE :searchWord ORDER BY cardFavourite ASC, cardClicked DESC, cardWord ASC")
LiveData<List<Card>> searchCardListRecents(String searchWord,int clicks, int keystage);
```

**Repository** my repository is a class full of calls to the database that return live data to their view model, the ones needed for this are :

```
public LiveData<List<Card>> searchFavouriteCards(String searchString){
    return cardDao.searchFavourites(searchString);
}

public LiveData<List<Card>> searchRecentCards(String searchString, int clicks){
    return cardDao.searchCardListRecents(searchString,clicks,keystage);
}
```

**View Model** my view model calls the repository methods using a switch map (for the searching)

```
public CardFavouritesViewModel(Application application, int clicks){
    cardRepository = new CardRepository(application);
    search = new MutableLiveData<>();
    cardRepository.getCardListByWordTypeAndWordDescription(args[0], args[1]);
    favourites = Transformations.switchMap(search, mySearch -> cardRepository.searchFavouriteCards(mySearch));
    recents = Transformations.switchMap(search, mySearch -> cardRepository.searchRecentCards(mySearch,clicks));
}

public LiveData<List<Card>> getLiveCardFavouriteList(){
    return favourites;
}

public LiveData<List<Card>> getLiveCardRecentsList(){
    return recents;
}
```

**Activity** and then my activity observes changes, as mentioned currently this is working in the sense that it does get the relevant data but its not working in respect that it duplicates the data and I don't have an obvious solution for clearing the list when its done any ideas welcome

```
ArrayList<Card> cardArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
cardFavouritesViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,
                new 
CardFavouritesViewModelFactory(getActivity().getApplication(),5))
.get(CardFavouritesViewModel.class);
       cardFavouritesViewModel.setSearchString(mSearchString);
       cardFavouritesViewModel.getLiveCardFavouriteList().observe(this, 
       new Observer<List<Card>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Card> cards) {
                cardArrayList.addAll(cards);
                cardAdapter.refreshList(cardArrayList);
                checkResults(cardArrayList.size());
            }
        });
        cardFavouritesViewModel.getLiveCardRecentsList().observe(this, 
        new Observer<List<Card>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Card> cards) {
                cardArrayList.addAll(cards);
                cardAdapter.refreshList(cardArrayList);
                checkResults(cardArrayList.size());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM card WHERE cardFavourite OR (cardClicked >= :clicks AND cardKeyStage <= :keystage)  AND cardWord LIKE :searchWord ORDER BY cardFavourite ASC, cardClicked DESC, cardWord ASC")
    LiveData<List<Card>> searchCardListRecentsAndFavourites(String searchWord,int clicks, int keystage);
```

Comment: but i want both, i want all cards marked as favourites, and cards with clicked value above X, i haven't tried youyr answer though so when i get a chance I will and update this

Comment: you got both: I use OR operator in query, i.e. if record marked as favourite you got it and if clicked > x you also got it in result

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this function will be helpful:

```
// Kotlin!!
fun <S, T, R> multiSourceLiveData(source1: LiveData<S>, source2: LiveData<T>, block: (S?, T?) -> R): LiveData<R> = MediatorLiveData<R>().apply {
    var data1: S? = null
    var data2: T? = null

    addSource(source1) {
        data1 = it
        value = block(data1, data2)
    }
    addSource(source2) {
        data2 = it
        value = block(data1, data2)
    }
}
```

use it like this:

```
    // Kotlin!!
    val allCardsLiveData = multiSourceLiveData(
        source1 = cardFavouritesViewModel.getLiveCardFavouriteList(),
        source2 = cardFavouritesViewModel.getLiveCardFavouriteList()
    ) { data1, data2 ->
        (data1 ?: emptyList()).plus(data2 ?: emptyList())
    }
    allCardsLiveData.observer(this) { allCards ->
        cardAdapter.refreshList(allCards);
        checkResults(cardArrayList.size());
    }
```

or

```
    // Java!!
    LiveData<List<Card>> allCardsLiveData = ExtensionsKt.multiSourceLiveData(
            cardFavouritesViewModel.getLiveCardFavouriteList(),
            cardFavouritesViewModel.getLiveCardRecentsList(),
            new Function2<List<Card>, List<Card>, List<Card>>() {
                @Override
                public List<Card> invoke(List<Card> data1, List<Card> data2) {
                    List<Card> result = new ArrayList<>();
                    if (data1 != null) result.addAll(data1)
                    if (data2 != null) result.addAll(data2)
                    return result;
                }
            });

     allCardsLiveData.observe(...
```

You can make several overloads of the function to support different numbers of sources.

Answer (score 0):

One more AND with cardFavourite column will work for you if the 2nd query is already working fine.

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM card WHERE cardFavourite AND cardWord LIKE :searchWord ORDER BY cardWord ASC")
        LiveData<List<Card>> searchFavourites(String searchWord);


   @Query("SELECT * FROM card WHERE cardFavourite AND cardClicked >= :clicks AND cardKeyStage <= :keystage  AND cardWord LIKE :searchWord ORDER BY cardFavourite ASC, cardClicked DESC, cardWord ASC")
        LiveData<List<Card>> searchCardListRecents(String searchWord,int clicks, int keystage);
```

Comment: this wont return cards marked as favourite for a clicked value of 0, I hadn't made this clear in my question originally so I've edited it to make this clearer, I want all cards that are marked as favourites, and all cards that have a value above clicks even if they aren't favourited